# Mostrar el ultimo registro como primero Firebase

Tags: firebase

Hola he estado aprendiendo a trabajar con firebase lo cual me a parecido maravilloso, pero por mi falta de experiencia me cuesta un poco entender su documentación, por eso pido su ayuda.

lo que quiero es que al mostrar los registros de mi base de datos en mi aplicación Web estos se impriman de abajo hacia arriba es decir que se muestre en mi app el último registro ingresado como primero y así de forma descendente he intentado usa 'ordenByChild()' pero no tengo resultado, también quisiera conocer como ordenar los registros haciendo referencia al valor de un nodo en este caso "fecha", también lo e intentado pero no tengo resultados dejare parte del código para ver si pueden darme una mano estaría muy agradecido

```
const dbNoticias = firebase.database().ref('noticias/').orderByChild('fecha')   
  dbNoticias.on('value', function(snapshot){
    var data= snapshot.val()
    $('#noticias').empty()
    var row=""
    for(noticias in data){
        var contenido= data[noticias].contenidoCorto
        var mostrar= contenido.substring('0', '100')
        row+='<div class="card-style animated fadeInDown">'+
             '<img class="img-card" src="'+data[noticias].url+'">'+
             '<div class="card-body">'+
             '<h3><b>'+data[noticias].titulo+'</b></h3>'+
             '<article>'+mostrar+' ... <a data="'+noticias+'" href="#" class="btnMostrar" >Leer más</a></article>'+
             '</div>'+
             '</div>'
    }
    $('#noticias').append(row)
    var row=""})
```

gracias ...

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database siempre te retorna en orden ascendente. No te puede devolver como tu lo quieres lo que podrias hacer es.

- Poner todo en una list y luego en el lado del cliente hacer un inverse() y recien hacer el for de los elementos.
- Usar una variable extra de timestamp pero que sea negativa para que te traiga la data inversa y de esta manera firebase te ordenara todo como lo quieres.

Saludos.